# JSP/R Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine

Tags: r, jsp

Please, I need your help.

I have this java class

```
package com.stephen.crawler;

import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JRI_Interface {

    Rengine r;
    String str_globalPath="/home/pavel/workspace/opendata/r_script/";

public JRI_Interface (String str_fuente) {
    r = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);
    r.eval("source(\""+str_globalPath+str_fuente+"\")");
}

public void exec_RProcedure(String str_procedure) {
    r.eval(str_procedure);
}

public String[] exec_RFunction (String str_procedure) {

    return r.eval(str_procedure).asStringArray();
}

}
```

And it works perfectly if I execute :

```
package com.stephen.crawler;

public class JRI_Start_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        JRI_Interface j = new JRI_Interface("staticdata.r"); 
        j.exec_RProcedure("loadParametersOD()");
        String obj[]=j.exec_RFunction("getLoadedParametersOD()");
        System.out.println (obj.length);

    }
}
```

However, when I execute using jsp with Tomcat :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"
%>
<%@ page import="com.stephen.crawler.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.rosuda.JRI.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<%
JRI_Interface j = new JRI_Interface("staticdata.r"); 
j.exec_RProcedure("loadParametersOD()");
String obj[]=j.exec_RFunction("getLoadedParametersOD()");
%>


<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the following message:

```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al
> procesar la página JSP /Inicio.jsp en línea 14
> 
> 11: <title>My Title</title> 
> 12: </head> 
> 13: <% 
> 14: JRI_Interface j = new JRI_Interface("staticdata.r");  
> 15: j.exec_RProcedure("loadParametersOD()"); 
> 16: String obj[]=j.exec_RFunction("getLoadedParametersOD()"); 
> 17: %> 
> 
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> causa raíz
> 
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
>   org.apache.jsp.Inicio_jsp._jspService(Inicio_jsp.java:146)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> causa raíz
> 
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine
>   com.stephen.crawler.JRI_Interface.<init>(JRI_Interface.java:12)
>   org.apache.jsp.Inicio_jsp._jspService(Inicio_jsp.java:124)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> causa raíz
> 
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>   com.stephen.crawler.JRI_Interface.<init>(JRI_Interface.java:12)
>   org.apache.jsp.Inicio_jsp._jspService(Inicio_jsp.java:124)
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Do I miss something?. I think I have configure everything.... .

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 6, all unpacked classes and resources in the **/WEB-INF/classes** directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the **/WEB-INF/lib** directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones.

The server environment is initialized in this order:

- Bootstrap classes of your JVM
- System class loader classes (fi, '$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext')
- **/WEB-INF/classes** of your web application
- **/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar** of your web application
- Common class loader classes (if you've no other option)
  ('common.loader' property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties)

Your servlet/webappX/jsp likely needs the class(es) or jar(s) in the bold directory(s).  Your server seems properly configured for Tomcat/jsp since it's showing errors in your code/config.  Your code that runs the REngine properly is allowed to use the command-line or env CLASSPATH but it's not that simple from Tomcat or other web server.  Hopefully it's just a matter of copying the REngine jar though you may have to tweak its config.

GL

Comment: Thanks. I did everything you said.. But nothing happens. In fact, directory WEB-INF/classes didnt exist. I had to create it.  I copied my class (JRI_Interface.class considering all the package path:com.stephen.crawler ) to this new directory, and my .jar (JRIEngine.jar) to WEB-INF/lib, however in Eclipse tree (project Explorer) those directories are empty.  Nothing happens =(